# Dummit and Foote Exercise 1.1 Problem 33

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x$ be an elementof order $n=2k$ in a group $G$.

Prove that $x^i=x^{-i}\iff i=k;1\leq i<n$.

If $i=k\implies x^{2i}=e\implies x^i=x^{-i}$

Conversely $x^i=x^{-i}=x^{2i}=e\implies 2k|2i\implies k|i\implies i\geq k$.How to show from here that $i=k$?

Comment: Hint $\langle x\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $2k$.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $1 \leq i<n$.

Comment: will you please explain how to use this fact @kccu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to kccu's suggestion,

Since i>=k and k|i, we have i = k, 2k, 3k, .... But since we have i < n = 2k, we get i = k.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^{j}=x^{-j}$ we can use the fact that,

$(x^{j})(x^{-j})=(x^{j})(x^{j})=x^{2j}=1$

Since $1 \leq 2j \leq n  \Rightarrow 2j=n \Rightarrow j=\frac{n}{2}=k$

N.B:  Remember that the identity is unique, so that the only other order $x$ can have is $n$.